# Color of errorbars with plots.jl

Tags: julia, plots.jl

I'm using the package Plots with the pyplot backend.
By default, errorbars are black. How can I change their color? I want to set it to the same color as the line itself (which should be the default behaviour imho).

```
using Plots
plot(1:3,1:3,yerr=0.1) # produces a blue line with black errorbars
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`markerstrokecolor`/`msc`sets the color. Normally you'd put points on the plot as well, rather than just the line with error bars, the default is thus to have the stroke around each point in the same color as the error bar. If you feel that another default is better you'd be welcome to open an issue on Plots.

Comment: How to automatically have the errorbars with the same color as the points?

Comment: Never mind, found out myself: `markerstrokecolor = :auto`.

Comment: `msc` only set the ends of the error bar for me - setting `lc=:red` sets all colours (markers + error bars) to the same colour.